# How to uniquely identify HTML contents of list elements(li) that is generated in a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I am auto generating a unordered list by putting one list element in a php loop, like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<a href=\"ArticleViewPage.php\" class=\"list-group-item col-sm\">". $row["Header"]."</a> ";
} 

$conn->close();
```

Lets say there are 10 rows in a table (table xyz contains 2 columns: id, header) where you pull the 'id' and 'header' from the database where the headers are shown as a list in an html page as a navigation bar (or menu).

How can I uniquely identify(find the id) when someone clicks on one of the list element and execute some code based on their selection?

(for example: when someone click one of the list item, I need to be able to send the id of this selected list item to a different php page and execute some code that is custom to that particular id/index.)

Note: The index/id of each list item cannot be manually typed in since the list is generated using a loop which pulls the headers from a database to full each list item as you can find above.

#### Please don't give a solution based on Jquery or other frameworks. Only simple concise php or javascript code please.

Comment: embed the index as a `data-index` attribute on the element, then use `event.target.dataset.index` from inside the click() event to grab the number. generically, `this` inside a _click_ event will refer to the clicked element, which might have some other "smoking gun" you can reach.

Comment: I'm not sure if you included the correct code. That PHP loop does not generate an unordered list.

Comment: @Don'tPanic He's probably using CSS to display it as a unordered list

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript Solution :**

You should attach click event to every element with class `list-group-item`, using `getElementsByClassName()` that will return an array of all objects with given class name so you could use for to loop through everyone of them and associate it with function you want to trigger on click (in my example this function called my_function), check example bellow :

```
function my_function() {
     //get the index of clicked li
};

var class_names= document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item");

for (var i = 0; i < class_names.length; i++) {
    class_names[i].addEventListener('click', my_function, false);
}
```

I suggest to add data attribute called `index` like @dandavis mentioned in comment, your code will be :

```
$i=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<a data-index='".$i."' href='ArticleViewPage.php' class='list-group-item col-sm'>". $row["Header"]."</a> ";
    $i++;
}
```

And you can get the index in your function using `getAttribute()` :

```
function my_function() {
     var current_item_index = this.getAttribute('data-index');
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add a variable like `$count=0;` before the loop, and print it within link `'href="ArticleViewPage.php?id=". $count ."";'` then `$count++;` last statement in loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by generating all of the links in an element that you have an `id` on (or any query selector) so that you can access it with JavaScript.

For example, if this is my generated HTML:

```
<div id="links">
  <a href="first.html">First</a>
  <a href="second.html">Second</a>
  <a href="third.html">Third</a>
  <a href="fourth.html">Fourth</a>
  <a href="fifth.html">Fifth</a>
</div>
```

I can use the following JavaScript to add a data attribute that will be the index of it, and add the click event listener and get access to that index:

```
enumerateLinks();

function enumerateLinks() {
  var links = document.getElementById('links');

  Array.prototype.slice.call(links.children)
    .forEach(function (link, index) {
      link.setAttribute('data-index', index);
      link.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    });
}

function handleClick(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); // Prevents navigation

  var clickIndex = evt.target.dataset.index;
  alert('Click index: ' + clickIndex);
}
```

[Here is a CodePen](http://codepen.io/tinacious/pen/MKZvvP).

You could also add a class to target each link as another person suggested but you would have to make sure that class wasn't used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any Javascript to accomplish this. If you want to pass the id from your query to `ArticleViewPage.php`, you can just append it as the query string to the `href` in your link.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<a href="ArticleViewPage.php?id=' .$row['id'] .'" class="list-group-item col-sm">'
          .$row["Header"] ."</a> ";
}
```

Then in `ArticleViewPage.php` the value will be available in `$_GET['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution will be just include the `id` and write inline code like

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "<a href=\"ArticleViewPage.php\" onClick=\"doAction(". $row["Header"].")\" class=\"list-group-item col-sm\">". $row["id"]."</a> ";
}
```

Define a `doAction` function and you get the database id of the row